# Dynamic SQL "USE [DB]" not worked

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, dynamic-sql

I use dynamic sql to create database an tables

this is sql script

```
DECLARE @DatabaseName VARCHAR(50) = N'test';
EXECUTE ('CREATE DATABASE [' +@DatabaseName+']');
EXECUTE('USE ' + @DatabaseName)
GO
CREATE SCHEMA [Framework]
GO
```

the error I get

```
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 1
There is already an object named 'Framework' in the database.
Msg 2759, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
CREATE SCHEMA failed due to previous errors
```

.

this error because   EXECUTE('USE ' + @DatabaseName) not work

I try to use

```
SET @SQL02  = 'USE ['+ convert(nvarchar(50),@DatabaseName) +']; SELECT DB_NAME();'
exec sp_executesql @SQL02
```

but not work

what I can do?

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (Perhaps SQL-Server?)

Comment: I used SQL version 2012

Comment: Executes run in their own instance. You should have all actions in the same EXECUTE command for the `USE <database>` to work properly.

Comment: Also, use `QUOTENAME()` when working with your `@DatabaseName` variable.

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(200); 
SET @Query = CONCAT('USE ', QUOTENAME('<MyDatabase>'), '; ', 'select DB_NAME();');

EXECUTE (@Query);
```

This will return `<MyDatabase>` as long as you remain within one `EXECUTE`.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer this form for remote execution:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = N'select Db_Name()';

<DatabaseName>.sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

You can put this logic into a more convenient form by making into a stored procedure:

```
create procedure dbo.usp_ExecuteSqlCommand (
    @databaseName sysname
  , @sqlCommand nvarchar(max)
)
as
begin;
    set nocount on;
    set xact_abort on;

    declare @innerStatement nvarchar(max) = @sqlCommand;
    declare @outerStatement nvarchar(max);

    set @databaseName = QuoteName(ParseName(@databaseName, 1), N'[');
    set @outerStatement = @databaseName + N'.sys.sp_executesql @stmt = @innerStatement;';

    execute sys.sp_executesql
        @stmt = @outerStatement
      , @params = N'@innerStatement nvarchar(max)'
      , @innerStatement = @innerStatement;
end;
```

Usage is obvious:

```
execute dbo.usp_ExecuteSqlCommand
    @databaseName = N'master'
  , @sqlCommand = N'select Db_Name();';
```

Comment: A rather elegant solution. Nice.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:(if you use execute, the db context will change only for that execute only)

```
DECLARE @DatabaseName VARCHAR(50) = N'test';
EXECUTE ('CREATE DATABASE [' +@DatabaseName+']');
use [test]
go
CREATE SCHEMA [Framework]
GO
```